# Executing background task in python and return API response quickly

Tags: python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, gevent, task-queue

API description

- I am creating a REST API in Flask
- POST API call **creates a new entry in DB and returns the primary key** of that entry to the

Long running task inside the API

1. Running a shell command that makes a **network call which lasts about 6/7 seconds**
2. Based on the output of the shell command, **updating the DB**

Main issue with above

- **We cannot have our API take such long time to return**
- Since our return value is NOT dependent on step 2,3 - **we can execute them in background**
- We can **return immediately** after creating an entry in DB and asking remainder to be done in background

How should we do this? (I can think of 4 ways)

- **Process pool** (am ok with scaling limitation)
- **Task queue & workers** (too much infra manage, setup)
- **Thread pool** (possible GIL, though not much)
- **AsyncIO/gevent** (might not allow API to return quickly)